# RegExp Remove content outside of commas

Tags: regex

Alright, so I have a database where you can get information from that'll show off in this kind of way:

> ID, Display name, Likes Cake, Likes Coffee, Likes Dogs

So if you get the information, it would show something a little like to this:

> 1,anonymous,1,0,1

Now it's not very popular so I would like to show the people who has answered this so I would like the "1,!anonymous!,1,0,1" (anything outside the !'s) gone. I looked around and found a RegExp code that would remove stuff outside quotes, but it's rather hard and I'm rather impatient to put all the display names in quotes.

So if there was a RegExp that would erase the numbers so I could put the usernames up, would be delicious.

Comment: isn't this just a csv file?

Comment: If it's a database, why not just ask for the Display name alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
 Replae '^[^,]+([^,]+).*' With '$1'
```

How it looks exactly in your language may vary, of course.

But in your case this looks like CSV, so isn't parsing the CSV file easier in that case? E.g. in PowerShell you could do

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | select 'Display name'
```

and likewise for other languages that have such parsing built-in somewhere. Besides, most other options may break depending on the input because fields in CSV may contain commas too which breaks both above regex and a naïve splitting method.

Comment: I tried this, and it seem to take a complete sentence instead of just the numbers + commas. I usually try in my favored notepad program to try and search for that RegExp and if I replaced your RegExp with nothing, it'd replace entire sentences. Thanks for the help though! - I only just noticed your edit, let me try that meanwhile

Comment: Yes, sorry, the replacement part was wrong. But as I was pointing out, a regex-based solution is probably the wrong approach here anyway.

Comment: Ah, your CSV parsing worked, much quicker and simpler than I expected RegExp to be. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the database result string and then get the relevant array index.

```
string dbString = "1,anonymous,1,0,1";
string username = dbString.Split(',')[1];

//value of username will be "anonymous"
```

Comment: I'll make sure to try this too, although the CSV parsing worked, the more knowledge the better. Thanks!